Raspberry plant with black streaks from the base
I've ordered a bunch of raspberry plants from a reputable nursery here in Italy.
One of them as this black streak that start from the base and goes upwards.
It also withers the leaves.
I don't think this is normal, maybe it's some kind of disease, but I can't pinpoint it.
I peeled the bark a bit, as you can see in the photos, and it's a bit brownish underneath.
Thanks in advance.





Is it just simple lignification? Please avoid in future to scratch barks unless you know what it is the problem: often you can just worsen things. Use a magnifier glass if you are unsure if it is a fungi or a tiny insect

@Giacomo, shouldn't this be an answer ?  :-)

@RohitGupta: it was mostly a rand (the "second" part). And first the "answer", I just assume it, but I'm not sure, and I do not want to tell: "it is nothing" when there is a disease. I hope somebody has more experience on raspberries

It seems like your plant is suffering from a disease called cane blight as it matches the symptoms such as black and dark streaks on the cane and browning under the bark. More symptoms involve wilting of the leaves and canes becoming brittle. So make sure to inspect your plant thoroughly. You can apply a fungicide to treat this disease after cleaning your plant and pruning off the infected area. However, you should also contact a plant expert to make sure that you have identified the right problem with your plant. Hope this helped.
